# WPF laggy scrolling in ItemsControl on a machine running Windows XP using .NET 4

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, itemscontrol

I am developing a WPF application that runs on a Windows XP machine. The machine has 1 Gb of RAM and runs at 0,9 Ghz. I am using .NET 4.0.

**Problem:**

- The scrolling of the ItemsControl on the client machine is slow / laggy / non-responsive.

**Setup:**

- The ItemsControl is bound to an ***ObservableCollection*** which
  holds 1000 items of type ***Event***. Each ***Event*** contains a *IList* of
  100 items of type ***Bet***.
- The DataTemplate of the ItemsControl holds StackPanel which itself
  contains six elements of type TextBlock. Each of those displays the
  property ***BetValue*** which is a member of ***Bet***. In this
  example I am only displaying the first six elements of the bet items
  collection.
- I am using a ***VirtualizingStackPanel*** in order to activate virtualization.

**Attempts:**

- I replaced the TextBlock element with a custom implementation (see ***FastTextBlock***) to get rid of possible overhead a TextBlock might generate. This led to a small increase in performance but overall it is still poor.

**Observation:**

- When I scroll slowly through the whole ItemsControl all of the items will be loaded into RAM. From now on scrolling is a lot smoother. However, GC will dispose / clear the items shortly which makes scrolling poor again.

**Questions:**

1. Based on the machine information and the setup I provided, is that the performance I should realistically expect? Are there any code optimizations or even hacks to increase the performance for Windows XP?
2. Is there a way to stop GC from disposing the items as scrolling is smooth once all items are loaded into RAM?
3. I don't want to remove virtualization because that would increase the intialization time dramatically. But I thought about an approach that would intially start with virtualization and intialize the remaining items in a background thread. Should I follow this approach?

**Code:** Here is some code in case someone is curious about the implementation.

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="WindowsX.View.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsXPTests"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WindowsXPTests.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Windows XP Test"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    Width="1024" Height="768">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            Content="Close"
            Height="50"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EventDummys}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <controls:FastTextBlock DataContext="{Binding BetsFirst}"
                                            Text="{Binding BetValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Width="50"/>
                    <controls:FastTextBlock DataContext="{Binding BetsSecond}"
                                            Text="{Binding BetValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Width="50"/>
                    <controls:FastTextBlock DataContext="{Binding BetsThird}"
                                            Text="{Binding BetValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Width="50"/>
                    <controls:FastTextBlock DataContext="{Binding BetsFourth}"
                                            Text="{Binding BetValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Width="50"/>
                    <controls:FastTextBlock DataContext="{Binding BetsFifth}"
                                            Text="{Binding BetValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Width="50"/>
                    <controls:FastTextBlock DataContext="{Binding BetsSixth}"
                                            Text="{Binding BetValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            Width="50"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        EventDummys = new ObservableCollection<EventDummy>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            EventDummys.Add(new EventDummy());
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EventDummy> EventDummys { get; set; }
}
```

**EventDummy**

```
public class EventDummy
{
    public EventDummy()
    {
        Bets = new List<BetDummy>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Bets.Add(new BetDummy
            {
                BetValue = App.Random.Next(3000)
            });
        };
    }

    private BetDummy betsFirstCache;
    public BetDummy BetsFirst
    {
        get
        {
            if (betsFirstCache != null) return betsFirstCache;

            betsFirstCache = (Bets == null) ? null : Bets.First();
            return betsFirstCache;
        }
    }

    private BetDummy betsSecondCache;
    public BetDummy BetsSecond
    {
        get
        {
            if (betsSecondCache != null) return betsSecondCache;

            betsSecondCache = (Bets == null) ? null : Bets.Skip(1).First();
            return betsSecondCache;
        }
    }

    private BetDummy betsThirdCache;
    public BetDummy BetsThird
    {
        get
        {
            if (betsThirdCache != null) return betsThirdCache;

            betsThirdCache = (Bets == null) ? null : Bets.Skip(2).First();
            return betsThirdCache;
        }
    }

    private BetDummy betsFourthCache;
    public BetDummy BetsFourth
    {
        get
        {
            if (betsFourthCache != null) return betsFourthCache;

            betsFourthCache = (Bets == null) ? null : Bets.Skip(3).First();
            return betsFourthCache;
        }
    }

    private BetDummy betsFifthCache;
    public BetDummy BetsFifth
    {
        get
        {
            if (betsFifthCache != null) return betsFifthCache;

            betsFifthCache = (Bets == null) ? null : Bets.Skip(4).First();
            return betsFifthCache;
        }
    }

    private BetDummy betsSixthCache;
    public BetDummy BetsSixth
    {
        get
        {
            if (betsSixthCache != null) return betsSixthCache;

            betsSixthCache = (Bets == null) ? null : Bets.Skip(5).First();
            return betsSixthCache;
        }
    }

    public IList<BetDummy> Bets { get; set; }
}
```

**BetDummy**

```
public class BetDummy
{
    public double BetValue { get; set; }
}
```

**FastTextBlock**

```
public class FastTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    private FormattedText formattedText;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        return formattedText != null ? new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height) : new Size();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (formattedText != null)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point());
        }
    }

    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FontSize", typeof(double), typeof(FastTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(16d));

    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FontWeight", typeof(FontWeight), typeof(FastTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(default(FontWeight)));

    public TextTrimming TextTrimming
    {
        get { return (TextTrimming)GetValue(TextTrimmingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextTrimmingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextTrimmingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextTrimming", typeof(TextTrimming), typeof(FastTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(default(TextTrimming)));

    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Foreground", typeof(Brush), typeof(FastTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(FastTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, (o, e) => ((FastTextBlock)o).TextPropertyChanged((string)e.NewValue)));

    private void TextPropertyChanged(string text)
    {
        var typeface = new Typeface(new FontFamily("Segoe UI"),
                                    FontStyles.Normal, FontWeight, FontStretches.Normal
        );

        formattedText = new FormattedText(
            text,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            typeface,
            FontSize,
            Foreground
        );

        formattedText.Trimming = TextTrimming;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and *very nice* first question! The only thing I would complain about is that you are using WinXP :)  But you put a lot of effort into your question, so kudos.